# Is it possible to track incoming and outgoing internet packages

Tags: windows-7, networking, packages

I have a simple program that synchonizes with the internet in certain amount of time.

I would like to see what data the program sends and receives.

How can I watch this data or at least show the address and time of the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a [packet sniffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) program for a Microsoft Windows system there is [WinDump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/), which is the command line equivalent of [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump), which is widely used on Unix, Linux, OS X, etc. systems. Or you could use a program with a Graphical User Interface (GUI), such as [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark). Nir Sofer also provides many [network monitoring tools at NirSoft.net](http://www.nirsoft.net/network_tools.html), including the following:

[SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) - Capture TCP/IP packets on your network adapter

[NetworkTrafficView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_traffic_view.html) - a network monitoring tool that captures the packets that pass through your network adapter, and displays general statistics about your network traffic.

If the program is using HTTP for transmissions, you can use his [HTTPNetworkSniffer](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/web/HTTPNetworkSniffer/) program.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I have tried Wireshark, great software, the only problem that it doesnot show the thread or application name that sends the requests.